# Match a field value with a value in a bag in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation in pig in the below format:

test = file::field1: chararray,x::y: {(z: chararray)}

Ex: test = a,({(a),(b),(c),(d)})

I want to check if field1 value (i.e., a) is present in the bag x. How to achieve this in pig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is no way to do this in pig. I have passed both field and bag to a python UDF and matched it there as below:

```
@outputSchema('matchindx:int')
def pythudf(field1,bag):
   for word in bag:
        if (word[0] == field1):
                return 1             
   return 0
```